# Can Azure Devops pipelines, where the build failed, show the user of the last commit when triggered with CI?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm doing Visual Studio builds on a self hosted agent, which are currently being triggered by the Continuous Integration setting in an Azure Devops pipeline.

When a build completes, it shows: Triggered by Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TFS
It also shows the repository, branch and revision number.

However, it is expected it would show Triggered by , If not showing the correct Azure Devops user, at least showing the Subversion user name, that would be something.

There was an expectation it would be possible to send email notifications to the user of the commit. (Not fool proof that they caused the problem, but the most convenient way to give the responsibility to somebody to make sure any build error gets resolved)

Does anybody know if a solution exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I couldn't Continuous Integration triggers to reliably work. They would always stop working after a short time. I'm surprised I have ran into so many issues with this, but I guess it just isn't that well supported.

Instead, now, I am queue the build via an svn post-commit hook which uses the azure devops REST API.

the REST API has setting, requestedFor":{"id":""}, where you can add the user id (which I also needed a rest api command to find)

A lot of messing around to get to this point, for a feature I expected to 'just work', hopefully this keeps working

Answer (score 1):

1. In both Classic and yaml pipelines, you can [specify a condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for a pipeline step. If you want it to run when the pipeline fails, it will be `condition: failed()` (in yaml), or `Control Options -> Run this task -> Only when a previous task has failed` (in Classic). Alternativel, you can check [Agent.JobStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) variable.
2. there's no predefined variable for current committer, but you can easily determine the last commit's author by using `svn` command, then log it. (any other version control system will have its own CLI that should allow it).

In yaml, it could look like this (using git instead of svn):

```yaml
steps:
... (your build)
- bash: | 
    author=`git log -1 --pretty=format:'%ae'` # get last commit author from git
    echo "last commiter: $author"
    # TODO: send email or other kind of notification
  condition: failed()
```

In classic one:

[image: classic condition]

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to this, hadn't even occurred to me it would be so simple to continue on error from the build job, then run a shell script. I assume that would allow for a few different workarounds

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong tool for you task. CI build will be triggered **after** changes was committed to branch. In that case it is not possible to fix those changes. As a result you will have history where a lot of revisions are not stable.

It might be more suitable for you to use [PR policy build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops). It is designed to validate **incoming** changes so target branch will be always stable and ready to some deploy. In this case, policy build will be triggered by PR creator so he will be informed about it's result. That can be configured in [personal notification settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops).

Comment: A task was not specified. Perhaps that information may be useful to somebody else.